# How to find defect in a Shiva linga or a Vigraham or a Shaligram

Tags: shiva-lingam, idols, shaligrama

I started performing Shiva pooja of the family pooja which was carried forward from great-grand father to grand father to father to mother and now me.  Are there any experts, priests who can see defects in the Shiva linga, Shaligram and other idols which may bring negative energies?

Comment: Do read properly before you accept an edit.

Answer (score 3):

For the time being a partial answer.

For an idol (Vigraha), the defects are presence of holes in it, broken, lacking in limbs etc.

In the Mahanirvana Tantram's Chapter 14 Lord Sadashiva enumerates these defects:

> **The wise man should not worship the image of a Deva which is broken or is holed, or which has lost a limb, or has been touched by a leper,
>   or has fallen on unholy ground** (100). The image of a Deva with
>   missing limbs, or which is broken or has holes in it, should be
>   consigned to water. If the image has been made impure by touch, it
>   should be consecrated, and then worshipped (101). The Mahapithas and
>   Anadi-lingas are free from all deficiencies, and these should always
>   be worshipped for the attainment of happiness by each worshipper as he
>   pleases (102).

I will update regarding defective Shiva Lingas later.

Answer (score 0):

About the Salagrama, the sastras say that even if there is a defect it is still worshipable.

> the seventh (having seven discs) to be Saṃkarṣaṇa; the eighth one (having eight discs) to be Puruṣottama; the ninth one (having nine discs) to be the nine modes; the tenth one (having ten discs) of his own nature; the eleventh (having eleven discs) to be Aniruddha; and the twelfth one (having twelve discs) is of the twelve forms. Discs more than these are seen on the stone called Ananta. **A broken, cut or broken Śālagrāma does not have a flaw**. He should carefully worship that image which is liked by him. He who carries the lord of stones after placing him on his shoulder, would subjugate the three worlds with the mobile and the immobile. Viṣṇu resides there where there is the Śālagrāma stone. The gift (given) there or the muttering of hymn or bathing done there is hundred times superior to that at Vārāṇasī, Kurukṣetra, Prayāga, Naimiṣa and Puṣkara.

This is an excerpt from Padma Purana.

There is more smritis that mention the same for Salagrama. Andy other deity of form with faults I believe should be discarded correctly with the correct procedures.